# Text node numbering and replacement for database indexing not sure how robust this would be

Tags: javascript, html, dom, text

Look for ++++ if you just want to see the code - preamble is just for context.

**pre-amble / explanation**

I am building an **offline** knowledge base for a client (i.e. entirely javascript with off-line ability to add pages - so can't use appcache for page content).

I have a WYSIWYG editor and was going to store the HTML version of the document and a stripped version (all HTML tags removed) separately in indexedDB/WebSQL (with the text version being used to search for key terms).

```
id    html    plain_text     //schema simplified
```

After a bit of thought I decided that it would be better to traverse all the text nodes and store each one of those in the database. Then replace the node text with ((X)) where X is the number of that node.

```
ID    pageID    NodeID    NodeText
```

and a second table

```
pageID    HTML
```

This seems to be the most efficient way to store the text for searches (as I can store each text nodes text in a separate row in the database rather than 1 huge block).

(FOR CLARITY)

```
<div id="cheese">Magical Content</div>
<ul><li>mystical content</li></ul>
```

would become

```
<div id="cheese">((0))</div>
<ul><li>((1))</li></ul>
```

with an array containing

```
0 => "Magical Conten", 1 => "mystical content"
```

That could then be stored in the database and used to reconstruct the page using the second version of the HTML.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**The Code bit if you want to skip the preamble that is only there for illustration of the 'why' (in case someone tells me I am an idiot and has a better suggestion!)**

Easiest way to see what I mean is to [check the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdbmugcz/5/)

Comment out `'convertNodeBack(div);` at the end to see what I mean about replacing text nodes with ((0)), ((1)) etc.

Check the console to see the array of text elements.

Then uncomment and re-run and the text should be replaced in the correct places. It seems to work ok and is fairly fast.

**My question is**

how robust is this as a solution - has anyone tried anything similar and come across any strange cases / edge cases??

Are there any cases where this won't work as expected?

Thanks in advance.

**JS Just incase anything happens to the fiddle (as I HATE link only questions!!)**

```
var start = new Date().getTime(); 

var textNodes = [];

//node, do you want a single string output or an array, do you want to match empty nodes?
function getTextNodesIn(node, singleString, includeWhitespaceNodes) {
var nonWhitespaceMatcher = /\S/;
//singlestringtext is used for a single string with all the page words.
var singleStringText = "";
//counter for the number of matches.
var counter = 0;

function getTextNodes(node) {

    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        if (includeWhitespaceNodes || nonWhitespaceMatcher.test(node.nodeValue)) {
            //remove line breaks and trim the string.
            var itemText = node.textContent.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"").trim();

            if(singleString){
                singleStringText += itemText + " ";
            }else{
                textNodes[counter] = itemText;
                node.nodeValue = "((" + counter + "))";
                counter ++;
            }

        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; ++i) {
            getTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }
}

getTextNodes(node);
 if(singleString){
                return singleStringText;
            }else{
               return textNodes;
            }

}


//converts a given document back to original
function convertNodesBack(node, singleString, includeWhitespaceNodes) {
var nonWhitespaceMatcher = /\S/;
var singleStringText = "";
var counter = 0;

function getTextNodes(node) {

    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        if(node.nodeValue.match(/\(\(([^)]+)\)\)/g)){
            var nodeNumber = node.nodeValue.replace(/[()]/g,'');

           node.nodeValue = textNodes[counter];
                counter ++;
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; ++i) {
            getTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }
}

getTextNodes(node);
 if(singleString){
                return singleStringText;
            }else{
               return textNodes;
            }

}



//convert page to node text mode.
var div =  document.getElementById('bodyText');
getTextNodesIn(div);

//convert page back to text from node text mode.
var div =  document.getElementById('bodyText');
convertNodesBack(div);
console.log(textNodes);

console.log(new Date().getTime() - start);
```

Comment: At the very least the function names are a bit confusing: `getTextNodesIn`, `getTextNodes`, `convertNodesBack`, `getTextNodes`. I like the idea, but how are you going to store the array of text nodes in the db? Different records? That's gonna be a lot. `NodeID` is just an incrementing int?

Comment: why not just store the innerHTML of the whole thing as one key? or at least each section, individual nodes seems to be overkill and fragile, though i can't spot a smoking gun... if you are loading them all into the document anyway, [ctrl]+[f] would be better than searching the DB anyway...

Comment: Sounds very similar to something Microsoft tried, before they were [*sued by l4i*](http://www.cnet.com/news/supreme-court-rules-against-microsoft-in-i4i-patent-case/) who had already patented the idea.  Markup was kept separate from content, with the markup applied for presentation by referencing positions within the text rather than mixing the markup and content as in various implementations of SGML.

Comment: I'm not sure it's helpful, but I made this: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/n23jcfz9/show/ and it's pretty fast. That was fun. Do with it what you want.

Comment: @Rudie Yeah - names are dumb I know - databases generally cope better being long rather than wide, especially in JS. Names shall be changed!

Comment: @dandavis that was the original idea - but efficiency wise on a search over hundreds of pages it will prove to be very slow. Ctrl + F would work on a single document - but this is a knowledge base with 100+ pages so it wouldnt work unfortunately. Thanks for looking it over

Comment: the client DB is important to storage, but limited in its search capabilities, especially indexedDB. in short, there is not the compelling reason to use the db for anything more than storage when all the data is local. the amount of data that can be fit in websql/indexedDB will fit comfortably in RAM, and you won't have to worry about storage interface quirks to perform your searches, helping your concerns stay separate. try searching an array vs indexedDB and see how the perf shakes out. there's no need to index if everything is in ram, and if it aint in ram, it won't fit anyway...

Comment: @dandavis, sorry but I don't quite see how that would work better, can you explain please? - are you saying load all 100 pages into RAM, then parse them? This isn't temporary storage - this is permanent storage - think of it as a very small Wikipedia that has no knowledge of a server. This application should run entirely without a server, from page creation to page storage and should be searchable by key term. Are you saying there is a better way as I thought I was making it more efficient this way.

Comment: another consideration is that modifying the DOM is very expensive and slow, so you want to change it as little as possible. if you write out each node like that, you're changing it a ton, and that will almost assuredly take much longer than an optimized DB query would save...

Comment: sorry we corssing over on comments - modification of dom on 3.5k lines with 800 nodes was 20ms on my PC - I cant live with that. What I need though is a way to search 100k+ lines effectively over multiple pages - hopefully the above point clarifies that bit - thanks for all the pointers though